# iSCSI vs a simple network share for a video editor

Tags: networking, network-shares, editing

I'm trying to understand the difference between iSCSI and network share protocols. iSCSI is a block-level protocol that allows remote access to storage devices over a network. Whereas network share protocol is a file-level protocol that enables sharing of files and folders over the network.

So, in your case, you have a NAS device on the network and you want to use it for video editing. You can use either iSCSI or network share protocol depending on your needs. If you want faster access to the data, you can use iSCSI as it provides block-level access. However, if you want to share files and folders easily, the network share protocol is the better option.

I need real-world use cases where they use both and what is the upside and the downside ?

Comment: iSCSI tends to dictate that only one machine can use that network drive at a time, if multiple people need access then iSCSI is not what you want unless you can guarantee that one computer is going to release the connection before another one takes control. iSCSI being *disk based* instead of *file based* (SAMBA, etc) means that there is far less granularity in what you can have going on in terms of clients.

Answer (score 1):

while there is some conceptual overlap, think of it as file sharing allows access to files, whereas iSCSI provides access to Disks (the disk itself, with its filesystem, not just the files that reside within it).

File sharing provides multi-user simultaneous-access concurrency handling and abstracts away the underlying filesystem so any computer with an appropriate client installed can access files even if the underlying volume would not be natively addressable when directly connected (ie a windows system can access a samba share that is physically stored on an BTRFS filesystem).

[iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) is primarily designed to be used in the datacenter, to connect servers and VMs to their disks, which are often physically installed in a different device like a SAN. Traditionally separating compute from storage required high bandwidth fiber channel connections directly between the server and the LUN on the SAN infrastructure, which is expensive and physically limiting.

iSCSI comes in because it provides a different paradigm for interacting with the remote disk, that allows it to operate over standard IP network links with reasonable performance. That alleviates some of the physical limitations, is definitely cheaper than dedicated connections, and allows more sophisticated architectures for the storage infrastructure.

As Mokubai points out, you can't have two computers working on the same hard disk at the same time, so access to an iSCSI volume is dedicated to a single system, just like a standard hard disk. This is primarily because IO operations must be coordinated by a single arbiter to avoid concurrency concerns that cannot be addressed otherwise.

So file sharing services and iSCSI are technologies designed to handle entirely different problems.